# Redirect after login , cached page issue - Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery, redirect

I'm encountering a problem with the creation of a redirect after login ajax, essentially after a correct login (for example, from the home page), I get redirected to a new page. While i'm in this new page, if i click on a link that takes me back to the home page, the home page is in the non-logged version. As if the browser maintain a cache version. In fact, simply by updating this page with F5 the page refreshes and i resulted logged in.

Do you have any suggestions?

**Edit: I'm using Wordpress LoginWithAjax Plugin**

```
/Make Ajax Call
    $.post(url, postData, function(data){
        lwaAjax( data, 'LoginWithAjax_Status', '#login-with-ajax' );
        if(data.result === true){
            //Login Successful - Extra stuff to do
            if( data.widget != null ){
                $.get( data.widget, function(widget_result) {
                    $('#LoginWithAjax').replaceWith(widget_result);
                    $('#LoginWithAjax_Title').replaceWith($('#LoginWithAjax_Title_Substitute').text());
                });
            }else{
                if(data.redirect == null){
                    window.location.reload();
                }else{
                    window.location = data.redirect;
                }
            }
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: you have to control it in the server, if you are using php, you have to validate if a session is active in the home page, if not display the login else redirect to new page...

Comment: but seems that no new GET is started by the browser when i came back from new page to home. Seems that simply last page is loaded from local browser cache!But i want to load home again! The server script works ok if i refresh manually the home page after redirect, than i think that is not a cookie/session problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting the session properly, like you mention in your comment, it's probably a browser cache. You can try adding a header to your page asking the browser not to cache:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Read more on this forum post:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/10628.htm

Comment: it seems to not working, i'm checking with Chrome, and it's continue to load from cache after inserting this code on my wordpress's header.php, i'm going to think that the hosting has installed or configured mod_header in apache

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to be working! thanks Tosh.

```
<?php 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
// HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```